# Использование "[sic]" в русском языке.

Tags: стилистика

Допустимо ли использование "[sic]" при цитировании в русском языке? Если да, то в каких стилях текста? В каких случаях (только при возможной ошибке в цитате или при любом "сомнительном" случае)? Как правильно оно (он? она?) записывается и произносится? Что делать, если там, откуда цитируешь, уже есть "[sic]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фактически (sic!) - именно в таком оформлении иногда используется в исходном латинском значении, т.е. когда пишущий хочет подчеркнуть, что в написаном нет непреднамернной ошибки. В цитате использование sic нежелательно, лучше после цитаты повторить привлекшее внимание слово или фразу с пометой "именно так!". Кстати, такой оборот вполне может служить заменой "(sic!)" в любом месте текста. 
Разумеется удалять из цитаты "sic!" не следует, если оно несет смысловую нагрузку. 
А вообще главный принцип - оговаривать, кому из авторов принадлежит помета.

Answer (score 0):

На Луркморе очень доходчиво написано про его историю и употребление:

> Изначально употреблялось в пометках
> текстов, как способ указать корректуре
> или наборщикам: да, в тексте ошибка,
> но в данном конкретном случае аффтар
> (sic!) имел в виду именно как
> написано, и граммар-наци могут
> ласаснуть тунтца. Латинское слово
> используется как раз потому, что
> функционал использовался ещё в те
> времена, когда книжки тиражировались
> путём переписи вручную монахами, и
> латынь была основным научным языком в
> Европе. Потом стало употребляться с
> целью обратить внимание читателя на
> то, какую чушь сморознул автор цитаты.
> На человеческую мову переводится как
> «я знаю, что это ошибка, но так есть в
> оригинале». Что делать — человечеству
> хочется лулзов. Олдфаги из этой страны
> знакомы с этим словом по работам
> Ленина, который активно употреблял его
> при цитировании дебильных высказываний
> оппонентов, и творчеству Евгения
> Замятина. На самом деле (sic!)
> вставляют в текст все кому не лень
> (sic!) и куда попало (sic!), так как
> мало кто действительно знаком с
> истинным (sic!) значением. Иногда это
> латинское словцо используют, чтобы
> выразить своё ироничное отношение к
> какому-либо утверждению. При этом
> автор текста чувствует себя неэпически
> умным — ещё бы, ведь он стебётся не
> просто так, а с применением латыни!
>
> > [Полная статья...](http://lurkmore.to/Sic)

---

Я считаю, такого в грамотной русской речи стоит избегать.

Comment: А что тогда делать с цитатами с ошибками (или "сомнительным" моментом, который следует особо выделить)? Писать сноску "да, в источнике написано именно так" каждый раз?

Comment: Я кактегорически не согласен с использованием Лукмора в качестве компетентного источника.