# Междометие «sic!»: происхождение и произношение

Tags: этимология, орфоэпия

Иными словами, откуда оно взялось и как его правильно произносить? Давно встречаю его в различных текстах разных авторов и непрестанно задаюсь этим вопросом.

Comment: Об использовании sic! и его истории см. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-sic-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: Ох, спасибо! Буду внимательней в следующий раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слышится, как пишется: сик!

Sic transit gloria mundi [Сик тра́нсит глё́риа му́нди] (типо того).

---

[Лурк рассказывает](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:dGcXJw4KvO4J:lurkmore.to/Sic%20&cd=4&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru):

***Sic (лат. такЪ!).***

> Пометка сия широко используется среди образованных людей, а не быдла
>   всякого. Также часто встречается в англоязычных текстах, так как
>   английский вообще содержит много служебных слов-латинизмов (i.e.,
>   e.g., ibid., q.v., etc.).
>
> Изначально употреблялось в пометках текстов как способ указать
>   корректуре или наборщикам: да, в тексте ошибка, но в данном конкретном
>   случае аффтар (sic!) имел в виду именно как написано, и граммар-наци
>   могут ласаснуть тунтца. Латинское слово используется как раз потому,
>   что обозначение использовалось ещё в те времена, когда книжки
>   тиражировались путём переписи вручную монахами и латынь была основным
>   научным языком в Европе.
>
> Потом стало употребляться с целью обратить внимание читателя на то,
>   какую чушь сморозил автор цитаты. На человеческую мову переводится как
>   «я знаю, что это ошибка, но так есть в оригинале». Что делать —
>   человечеству хочется лулзов.
>
> Ныне обычно втыкается в самое неподходящее место цитируемого текста
>   для того, чтобы показать, что это не автор данного текста натыкал
>   ошибок и опечаток, обкурился или под веществами, а также особо корявых
>   конструкций, — а так оно и было в исходнике. Фактически это более
>   модная замена приписке «орфография оригинала цинично сохранена» —
>   вплоть до того, что некоторые ошибочно считают sic аббревиатурой от
>   «spelling is correct» или «same in copy» (sic!).
>
> Также используется, чтобы подчеркнуть удивительность какого-нибудь
>   факта (по крайней мере, авторами игрожура). Для подчёркивания
>   удивительности факта часто используется более короткий вариант —
>   восклицательный знак в скобках (!).

Не нравится речь Луркоморья, можно почитать то же, но "облагороженно" в Википедии:

[***Sic***](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)

Comment: А *глёриа* — это тамбовский акцент? ) Почему же не *глориа*?

Answer (score 1):

**SIC** (sik, *Eng*. sik)
[***Sic*** itur ad astra — **так** идут к звёздам]

*Sic* – латинское слово, обозначающее *так, таким образом, именно так, так есть.*
Предназначено для того, чтобы показать, что предыдущее неправильное или необычное написание является цитатой, а не ошибкой при печати или написании. Обычно выделяется *курсивом* и помещается в квадратные **[*sic*]** или круглые скобки **(*sic*)**, нередко после него ставится восклицательный знак **(*sic!*)**.
 [**Краткий словарь сленга**](https://pw.mail.ru/forums/showthread.php?t=59721)

Представьте, что вы обнаружили в цитате орфографическую, грамматическую или смысловую ошибку. Теперь, для того, чтобы ее обозначить, следует поставить знак ***sic***, обязательно взяв его в скобки.
Этот знак позволяет сообщать читателю, что ошибка в цитате соответствует первоисточнику и не является вашей ошибкой.
Например:
*Mr. Smith says of the experience, "I'm not sure but possibly that fish was something extraterestrial **[sic]**." — Мистер Смит рассказывает о происшествии: "Я не уверен, но, возможно, эта рыба имеет внеземное происхождение **[sic]**".*

*Раскрою один небольшой секрет: я очень люблю сёрбать **[sic**, т. е. не "сербáть"**]** , когда пью горячий чай в одиночестве. Так реально гораздо вкуснее.*

Иногда используется в рукописях и статьях(с восклицательным знаком), как замена длинной фразы: "***так в тексте***, прошу обратить на это **особое** внимание!"

*Из слов мнимогерманского и норманнского происхождения Круг приводит следующие: князь, пенязь, усерязь, витязь, шляг **(sic!)**, стерляг, пуд, суд, град, грид **(sic!**), ряд, скот, хлеб, шнек **(sic!)**, полк, вира, месячина...*